# El log retorna error y en la pantalla sale undefined

Tags: php

Desarrollando una carrito de compras uso objetos y variables de session.

```html
<?php
session_start();

require ("../../models/claseTicket.php");


    if (isset($_POST['accion'])){
   if ($_POST['accion']=="listar"){

    if(isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){
             $carrito = $_SESSION['carrito'];
             echo json_encode($carrito);
        }else{
         
      $carrito = array();
      echo json_encode($carrito);
        }
        
    
    
   }else if ($_POST['accion']=="agregar"){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $pu = $_POST['precio'];
        $cant = $_POST['cantidad'];
        $nom = $_POST['nombre'];
        $detalle = new detalleTicket($id,$pu,$cant,$nom);
       
        
 
        
        if(isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){
            $carrito = $_SESSION['carrito'];
        } else {
            $carrito = array();
        }
        
        array_push($carrito, $detalle);
      
        $_SESSION['carrito'] = $carrito;
        
    }
    
  
   
}   


?>
```

Y este es el pedido AJAX, como veran muestro "data":

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
listarDetalle();

});
function listarDetalle(){
     var accion="listar";
      
    $.ajax({
     
            type: "POST",
            url: "//localhost/gestionweb/includes/php/procesoDetalle.php",
            data: { "accion":accion}, 
           dataType:'json',
        
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
               
            },
            
            success: function(data){
              
          console.log(data);
          
                                   
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].idp + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].precio + "</td>" 
                    "<td>" + data[i].cantidad + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].pu + "</td>" +
                    "<td><input type='radio' id='"+data[i].idp+"' name='seleccion'/></td>"+
                    "</tr>";
                $(newRow).appendTo("#ticket tbody");                 
       
    
               
            
        
  

        } }
        
}).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

  if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

    alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

    alert('Requested page not found [404]');
  

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');

  } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

    alert('Time out error.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

    alert('Ajax request aborted.');

  } else {

    alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

  }

});;

};
```

El array llega pero obtengo este error:
**(7) […]​0: Object { __PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name: "detalleTicket" }​1: Object { __PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name: "detalleTicket" }​2: Object { __PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name: "detalleTicket" }​3: Object { __PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name: "detalleTicket" }​4: Object { __PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name: "detalleTicket" }​5: Object { __PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name: "detalleTicket" }​6: Object { __PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name: "detalleTicket" }​length: 7​: Array [] ticket.js:22:11**

Y en las columnas de la tabla dice undefined.

El metodo que agrega un producto esta en otro archivo .js pero es el siguiente:

```js
$("#Agregar").click(function(event){
  var cantidad=$("#CANTIDAD").val();
  if (cantidad!==""){
    var accion = "agregar";
    $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/includes/php/procesoDetalle.php",
            data: {accion,id,cantidad,nombre,marca,precio}, 
            
  dataType:'html',
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){
               
                      
            }
        })
```

Adjunto la clase Ticket:

```html
<?php
require_once ("/../includes/claseConexion.php");
require_once ("claseProducto.php");

class detalleTicket{
    
    private $idp;
    private $precio;
    private $cantidad;
    private $nombre;
    private $subtotal;
    
   
   public function __construct($id,$pu,$cant,$nom){
    
    
    $this->idp=$id;
    $this->precio=$pu;
    $this->cantidad=$cant;
    $this->nombre=$nom;
    $this->subtotal= ($this->cantidad * $this->precio);
   
   }
   public function setSubtoal($sub){
    
    $this->subtotal=$sub;
    
   }
   public function actualizaCantidad($nueva){
    
    $this->cantidad=$this->cantidad + $nueva;
    $sub= $this->cantidad * $this->precio;
     $this->setSubtoal($sub);    
    
   }
}
class Ticket{
  private $id;
  private $detalle = array();
  private $fecha;
  private $hora;
  private $total;
  private $stm;
  private $vuelto; 
  
  public function __construct(){
    

    
  }
  public function agregaDetalle(detalleTicket $d){
    
    $this->detalle[] = $d;
  } 
  public function setTotal($val){
    
    $this->total=$val;
    
  }
public function listarArt(){
    
  return $this->detalle;
}
public function registrar(){
    //me conecto a la bd
    $conexion = Conexion::singleton_conexion(); 
 try{

    $conexion->beginTransaction();
    $queryid="select comprobante from identificadores;"; 
     $array=$conexion->query($queryid);
   foreach($array as $a){
    $id = $a['comprobante'];
      }
 
  $qnuevoid="UPDATE identificadores SET comprobante=".++$id.";";
  $conexion->query($qnuevoid);
  
        $queryticket="insert into despensa.ticket (idticket, fecha, total,vuelto) values (".$id.",'".$this->fecha."',56,88);";
  $conexion->query($queryticket);

   $conexion->commit();
   
 }catch(Exception $e){
   $conexion->rollBack();
     echo "Fallo: " . $e->getMessage(); 
 }
 

    
}
}


?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que no esta leyendo la clase `detalleTicket`

Comment: Y porque? como podria resolverlo?

Comment: Asegurate que el nombre de la clase sea correcto, que el path del require tambien sea el correcto y que el constructor reciba los parametros correctos.

Comment: proba el require antes del start_session (si hay un objeto/clase en la session y no puede des serializar el objeto para armar el array `$_SESSION`, da ese error)

Comment: Lo hice, sigue en undefined pero muestra objetos vacios en la consola.

Comment: ahí ya coincido con @alanfcm puede que sea el constructor, un par de vardumps a ver que se genera te puede dar una pista

Comment: Gracias, <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: id in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionweb\includes\php\procesoDetalle.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: precio in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionweb\includes\php\procesoDetalle.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: nombre in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionweb\includes\php\procesoDetalle.php</b> on line <b>27</b><br /> Obtengo esos errores pero esas variables si la estoy enviando en el click de Agregar, porque falla, la cantidad no falla

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega tu archivo claseTicket o donde definas la clase

Comment: Me parece que esto no es correcto: `data: {accion,id,cantidad,nombre,marca,precio}`  ahí no estás enviando nada, debes  construir tu variable data con pares `llave:valor`, algo así más o menos: `data: {accion: accion, id: id, cantidad: cantidad, nombre: nombre, marca: marca, precio: precio}` ... Tienes los *undefined index*  porque no encuentra las llaves en el array.

Comment: Hay puse el codigo de claseTicket.php, no faltara serializar el objeto?

Comment: @alanfcm probe poner el incio desesion despues del require de la clase. Y no da mas ese error pero llega vacio el objeto, el log del array devuelve un objeto vacio